# Get specific point in referer of apache access.log

Tags: linux, bash, apache-http-server

How can i get referer from apache access.log whitout the "GET" and "HTTP/1.1"?

```
cat $APACHELOGFILE | awk -F\" '{print $2}
```

The Output is: GET /folder/xpto/ HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logfile looks like this:

```
10.20.30.40 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:39:21 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://www.domain.tld/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
```

and you want the referer use:

```
awk '{print $11}' $APACHELOGFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the cut command to remove the first number of characters.

Cut -c 10

To remove first 10 characters

Comment: And another way to improve this entire thing: use `cut -c 10 < $APACHELOGFILE` to prevent cat from making another process.